# Wget - repeat download of the same image from URL (with backup and timestamping)

Tags: wget, webcam

I am trying to download images from a webcam that refreshes the image about every 3 seconds.

I want to use the timestamping option in case their webcam stops updating the files (happens from time to time)

What is the command for repeating the same download with a waiting time of 3 seconds in between and then downloading the new one (while keeping all the previous files)

Something like:
`wget --recursive -wait=3 --timestamping http://apollo.prg.aero/kamera/image.jpg`

? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In bash, something like this could work:

```
while true
do 
  now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
  wget --output-document="/home/${now}_my_image.jpg" http://apollo.prg.aero/kamera/image.jpg
  sleep 3
done
```

Used this for inspiration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever